# Does std::allocator_traits define rebind_alloc if rebind not present in custom allocator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, allocator

I'm trying to rebind my custom allocator type, `MyAllocator<foo>`, for use in a `basic_string` class, e.g.:

`std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char>> ...`

The allocator is passed to the context as `MyAllocator<void>`, so I need to rebind the allocator.

From the cppreference page for `std::allocator_traits`, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits:

> Member alias templates:
>
> `rebind_alloc<T>`:    `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` if present, otherwise `Alloc<T, Args>` if this Alloc is `Alloc<U, Args>`

My custom allocator implements `allocator_traits`, but does not define the rebind struct (which doesn't appear to be a requirement to implement `allocator_traits`). My understanding of the documentation is that it `allocator_traits` should understand `rebind_alloc`. However, if I try calling `rebind_alloc` on my custom allocator type:

```
template<typename T>
using RebindAlloc =
  typename std::allocator_traits<MyAllocator<void>>::template rebind_alloc<T>;
```

I get various compiler errors when I try to pass `RebindAlloc<char>` to the `basic_string` type:

```
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/string:52:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:114:41: error: 
  'rebind' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
  typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_CharT>::other _CharT_alloc_type;
```

Clearly the documentation has misled me. Should I just give up on `rebind_alloc` and implement rebind in the custom allocator, or is there a correct way of doing this using `allocator_traits`?

I am using gcc 4.8 with C++11. 14 is not an option at the moment.

Here's a code snippet of what I'm trying to do:
https://gist.github.com/jacquelinekay/0cee73d1d2d78d8edd31

Comment: can you post a minimum (almost) compilable example that I can plug into my compiler to check?

Comment: I've edited it with a code snippet that should be valid, except for the compile error mentioned in the original post that I can't figure out.

Comment: @Jackie compiles fine starting from gcc 5.1

Comment: ah, thanks for checking that. So the documentation is correct, but 4.8 has an incomplete implementation of the standard, then?

Comment: @Jackie you can look up if there's any bug reported for stdlib not using allocator traits for operating on allocators. I'm not sure if the stdlib is forced to use them, I guess it is, but it was not implemented for `std::basic_string`

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56437

Comment: Thanks everyone for clarifying the problem. I'm in a situation where I can't change my compiler (working on a library targeting developers on gcc 4.8).

I implemented a workaround for this particular issue, but now I'm running into the same bug trying to pass a custom allocator to std::shared_ptr. Anyone know a good workaround to make my allocator compatible with this interface?

Comment: @Jackie ask a new question with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), *"I'm having a problem"* isn't very descriptive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am using gcc 4.8 with C++11.

Then you need to define `rebind` in your allocator, GCC's `basic_string` doesn't support the C++11 allocator requirements until version 5.1 (and then only for the new ABI string, i.e. `std::__cxx::basic_string`).

So your allocator must meet the C++03 Allocator requirements, defining all the members, because `allocator_traits` isn't used by string in 4.8

Answer (score 4):

[n3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) says in [allocator.traits.types]/10:

> ```
> template <class T> using rebind_alloc = see below;
> ```
>
> *Alias template:* `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` if such a type exists; otherwise, `Alloc<T, Args>` if `Alloc` is a class template instantiation of the form `Alloc<U, Args>`, where `Args` is zero or more type arguments; otherwise, the instantiation of `rebind_alloc` is ill-formed.

which agrees with cppreference.  It (allocator traits) seem to have been added in C++11, so it does not appear in [n1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf).  Further archaeology could detect where it arrived, but that isn't all that relevant.

It appears as if your compiler is not a compliant C++11 compiler in this regard.

With minor fixes, [both gcc 5.2.0 and clang 3.7.0 in C++11 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7629a3afcd3913e7) will compile your code without error.

It appears the only reasonable response, if you cannot change your compiler, is to implement a simple `rebind`.